# Ubuntu stuck on installer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I've just got a new Acer laptop with Windows 8.1, 1TB storage and 4GB RAM. I've downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu and used a USB as the boot option. Before this, I partitioned my HDD into a 800GB drive and a 200GB drive (the latter to be used for Linux). I changed the boot priority order in the BIOS so that it would boot from the USB first, which lead me to a Ubuntu installer screen at which point I selected "Install Ubuntu". I am now left with a loading screen which isn't showing any signs of progress that looks like:

http://i1243.photobucket.com/albums/gg558/squiffyk7/Ubuntuscreen.png

How could I get out of this without corrupting my laptop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen a screenshot in your question. My questions are 1. How much time did you waited? 2. Were those 5 dots blinking? 
I my case I got stuck around 10 min. I think you should wait longer. And those blinking dots suggest that system is working and you should wait.

Comment: I waited 3-4 hours the first time, since your post I've rebooted and tried running Ubuntu before installing, and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Check that you have downloaded complete .iso by checking md5sum which you install on pen drive.

Comment: Try pressing the arrow keys. They may swap the screen out with a text based console listing what your computer is doing at the moment. The contents of that screen will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons this could be happening.

> > First, be sure to format your USB completely, I recommend using Rufus to create the flash drive as it formats it as well as makes the bootable USB for you.
> >
> > Secondly, be sure that you give plenty of time for the loading screen to work. Depending on your hardware it could take up to an hour or more. On my laptop it took about 45 minutes to initialize.
> >
> > Third, be sure download the proper ISO and check the md5sum. I have noticed many times in the past that the ISO will affect the install. Either an incomplete download, or corrupted version of the ISO can cause this issue. When you download the ISO ensure you are using a wired connection.

This should resolve your issue, but the two main points would be to use Rufus to create the bootable USB drive, and to ensure you are using wired internet when downloading the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  Use the f12 for boot order or another key. (Should be that key for acer)
Also try another USB installer.   Universal usb installer is good.
Using a pre-installed ubuntu to make a startup disk is also good.
Click on "format disk" to format it even if the disk is clean. 
This makes a bootable disk.

Sometimes a pop up windown comes up when installing software and it may be behind another window.  This is unlikely for your case, but it happens when you are in ubuntu or windows.  An example is installing wine and the Microsoft fonts popular window.

Limit your persistence to 1gb and then 0 if that does not work. 
It should take less than 3 minutes to boot.  1 minute is more likely.  It depends on how big the persistence disk is.

I had a similar boot problem with a friend's computer last night and making a universal installer worked.